# Vuex access modules in subdirectories

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have the following directory structure:

- store

  - modules

    - file1.js
    - file2.js
    - file3.js
    - anotherFolder

      - filex1.js

My question is, how to access the state of **anotherFolder/filex1.js**
I can set the value, but I can't get it.

```
this.$store.dispatch('anotherFolder/filex1/myAction', {}) //work

let val = this.$store.state.anotherFolder.filex1.myValue //not work
```

I am importing the modules as follows.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import getters from './getters'

Vue.use(Vuex)
const modulesFiles = require.context('./modules', true, /\.js$/)
const modules = modulesFiles.keys().reduce((modules, modulePath) => {
  const moduleName = modulePath.replace(/^\.\/(.*)\.\w+$/, '$1')
  const value = modulesFiles(modulePath)
  modules[moduleName] = value.default
  return modules
}, {})

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules,
  getters
})

export default store
```

my filex1.js

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
      myValue: {}
    },
    actions: {
      myAction({ commit }, reg) {
        commit('MY_ACTION', reg)
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      MY_ACTION(state, reg) {
        state.myValue = reg
      }
    }
  }
```

I want to organize the store's files in subdirectories so I don't have everything in the modules folder.
thanks!

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(modules)` from the store index?

Comment: Why do you have getters at the Vuex root rather than in each of the modules ? Create getters in every module and then use `mapGetters` inside your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the binding helpers provided by vuex in your component to access the state in a nested module:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    a: state => state.some.nested.module.a,
    b: state => state.some.nested.module.b
  })
```

}

see:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

Comment: I had to add the module path mapState('dir/subdir/subdir'